# In C function declaration 'params, ...)' equal to 'params...)'?

Tags: c, glusterfs

all
In glusterfs's functions, there is one as follows
NOTES: the whole define in [stack.h](https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/blob/devel/libglusterfs/src/glusterfs/stack.h#L310)

```
//libglusterfs/src/glusterfs/stack.h

#define STACK_WIND(frame, rfn, obj, fn, params...)                             \
    STACK_WIND_COMMON(frame, rfn, 0, NULL, obj, fn, params)

#define STACK_WIND_COMMON(frame, rfn, has_cookie, cky, obj, fn, params...)     \
    do {                                                                       \
        ...  \
        next_xl_fn(_new, obj, params);                                         \
        THIS = old_THIS;                                                       \
    } while (0)
```

I did not google search anything about explaining such declaring methods, any idea will be appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params...` as part of function-like macro is a GNU extension before C standardized ellipsis as part of arguments of function-like macros.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros

Nowadays, prefer `__VA_ARGS__`.

> In C function declaration 'params, ...)' equal to 'params...)'?

No, they are not equal in function-like macros. The first one needs to use `__VA_ARGS__` to reference variadic arguments and use `__VA_OPT__` or `##__VA_ARGS__` to remove leading comma. In the `params...` then `params` is straight up replaced by all the arguments including commas.

Doing just ellipsis `, ...)` and using `__VA_ARGS__` would be equal to `, params...)` and using `params`.

In normal functions `params...` as part of parameter-list is just invalid.

Comment: from the whole define including STACK_WIND_COMMON，the 'params...' does not seem to be invalid

Comment: ^_^ sorry for "the above comment", I only hope make my doubts clearer.